# WindsorContainer ctor takes 4 seconds

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

doing this:

```
  new WindsorContainer()
```

takes 4 seconds, sometimes 7

I did some performance tests with DotTrace and found that the problem is in this method:

```
Castle.Windsor.Diagnostics.PerformanceMetricsFactory.Initialize()
```

which at the end does this:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.InternalGetValue(String, Object, Boolean, Boolean)
```

**anybody knows how to make it not to do this, so that the constructor would work instantly and not 4 seconds?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Windsor 3 beta 1. Performance counter is opt-in in current trunk (as it will be in final version 3)

Comment: could, you please show me how to downgrade this line: `Container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed(a).Pick().WithService.FirstInterface().LifestylePerWebRequest())` to v. 2.5.1.0, the .LifestylePerWebRequest() doesn't exist in this version

Comment: did it like this `Container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed(a).Pick().WithService.FirstInterface().Configure(o => o.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest))`